# django template extend - all but one template

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a piece of html that I want present in all pages, except one. If not for this page, I would have put it in the `base.html` and extended.

Is there a way other than putting the code individually in all the required pages?

Answer (score 2):

From template-inheritance [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance),

The template engine will notice the **{% block %}** tags in base.html and replace those blocks with the contents of the child template.

**BUT**

> If the child template didn’t define the block, the value from the
>   parent template is used instead. Content within a **{% block %}** tag in a
>   parent template is always used as a fallback.

So in that case you can use **{% block %}** tag in the base.html.

```
{% block content %}
 <!-- Your content here-->
{% endblock %}
```

You don't have to define that block in every template as the parent **{% block %}** is used as an fallback.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

So in your exceptional case just define that **{% block %}** tag with no data or something else.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
 <!-- Nothing goes here -->
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put it into a block that gets overridden with nothing in order to have it ignored. For example:

**base.html**

```
{% block content %}
    <div>
        This should show on all pages except for this one
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

**included-page.html** (The div will be included on this page)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
```

**ignored-page.html** (The div will be ignored on this page)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
```